# How to sort two varchar columns order by

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar

By default if you write order by it is considered as ascending order and if you want like highest to lowest use as: order by desc. But my question is how to sort two things like I have name and class (VarChar) both how can i sort them both? Please help. I am using MySQL query: select name,class from student order by name asc, class asc; but it's not showing what I want. Data is like: name: Mike class: Four

```
select name,class from student order by name asc, class asc;
```

Comment: Show us the data ordered in your wanted way.

Comment: And what do you expect? You cannot sort by both in the same weight because then you would have wrong results. So its sorting first for name and then for class.

Comment: then you should store class as number `4` not `Four`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Good point. Perhaps that what he wants

Comment: I was practicing mysql I am not sure what results to accept but as far as I understand I think name should be sorted and class also like I've class as One Two and Three it must come as One, Two, Three so as for names like Zoya, Asad and John should print as Asad, John and Zoya @DevsiOdedra

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff help please

Comment: @shadow, seems like the question here is how to sort numbers written as words as numbers, not alphabetically.

Comment: As Devise mentioned, You cannot sort on alphabetical numbers. Four is sorted before one because F is before O. So you must enter your classes as integers values to be able to sort correct

Comment: @jarlh you are right!

Comment: @AliAsadullahShah, or have a mapping table storing numbers both as digits and words, which you JOIN.